# A positive polynomial in two variables which has no minimum value

Tags: calculus

I'm wondering a positive polynomial in two variables defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (i.e $f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f,(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$) which has no minimum value

Could anyone construct such a polynomial? Thanks in advance for anyone's help!

Comment: If $a,c$ have opposite signs then $f$ has no global minimum. And $f(x,y)=-x^2-y^2$ doesn't even have a local minimum

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen a positive polynomial I mean a polynomial whose values are always positive

Comment: what is $ef$? is it a constant?

Comment: I think it is impossible due to Gauss decomposition into linear combination of squares of first degree polynomials, which is necessarily with signature (+,+,+). But I have to enter into the details...

Comment: @JeanMarie I think so too. This is almost impossible.

Comment: @JeanMarie  the first thing that comes to my mind $$a\left(x+\frac{by+d}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4a(cy^2+ey+f)-(by+d)^2}{4a^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

There are infinitely many such polynomials.

Take

$$a=b=c=d=e=g<0$$

You get,

$$\min \left\{f(x,y\right\}=-\infty$$

Comment: I don't understand: the OP asks for a polynomial taking only positive values...

Comment: @JeanMarie OP edited the original question after I answered. $\ddot\smile$. I answered the original question.

Answer (score 1):

A $\textbf{positive polynomial}$ on a set $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is a polynomial whose values are positive on $S$.

So here is one example. Let $S=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2 <1 \}$, an $\textit{open}$ disk of radius $1$, and $f(x,y) = 1-x^2-y^2$.

Then $$\displaystyle{\min_{(x,y)\in S}} \: f(x,y)=\varnothing, $$ i.e., does not exist. However
$$
\inf_{(x,y)\in S} \: f(x,y) = 0.
$$